# Python: advantages and disvantages of _mysql vs MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql

Two libraries for Mysql.
I've always used _mysql because it's simpler.

Can anyone tell me the difference, and why I should use which one in certain occasions?

Comment: I think this will most certainly be of interest... http://charlesnagy.info/it/python/python-mysqldb-vs-mysql-connector-query-performance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQLdb uses DB-API (described in [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)) which should be preferred, since it's common to all database drivers. IMHO there is no advantage in going low-level with `_mysql`. I'd rather think of using higher level libraries, like [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org), instead.

Comment: `_mysql` needs to exist to connect the higher level api to the C libraries. The `_` should be a clue that you usually shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can use [MySQL Connector/Python](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy):

> MySQL Connector/Python is implementing the MySQL Client/Server protocol completely in Python. This means you don't have to compile anything or MySQL doesn't even have to be installed on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

_mysql is the one-to-one mapping of the rough mysql API. On top of it, the DB-API is built, handling things using cursors and so on.

If you are used to the low-level mysql API provided by libmysqlclient, then the _mysql module is what you need, but as another answer says, there's no real need to go so low-level. You can work with the DB-API and behave just fine, with the added benefit that the DB-API is backend-independent.