# Scripting mysql for retrieving data in a loop

Tags: php, python, mysql, shell, scripting

Background: Non developer with bash shell scripting knowledge needs to query a READ ONLY DB instance and generate data for given variables.

Data in existing file

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
......
...
....
An Bn
```

I would like to connect to the mysql database within the bash script and loop through a select statement "n" number of times

```
select x, y,z from table tablet_vendors where a=A1 and b=B1
```

except that A1 and B1 need to be passed as parameters first time, A2 and B2 next time and to n in a for loop. I know the shell side of things, but don't know how to integrate both.

Tried something that can define all possible values for "a" at the beginning of the shell script, but it's way too tedious. Any help is appreciated.

I am open to suggestions on using other scripting languages if they are easy to work with mysql and if you can provide some guidance. My searches are pointing to php and python??

Comment: First learn how to communicate with mysql: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler version:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
import csv

con = mysql.connect('localhost','user','password','dbname')
cur = con.cursor()

q = "select x, y,z from tablet_vendors where a=%s and b=%s"

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
  rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
  for row in rows:
     cur.execute(q,row)
     result = cur.fetchone()
     while result:
        print result
        result = cur.fetchone()
```

Any errors thrown by MySQL will stop execution. You can wrap the `cur.` lines in a try/except block to be more elegant.

Comment: how can this be more "elegant" since i do the same thing with try/except? secondly, you don't select any db above, meaning the SQL query will fail due to not slected a db prior to execution.
And the _mysql lib has the same features as you just described except that you'll become limited in some senses.

Comment: And secondly, there's another flaw in your query.
You prepare the string for taking two parameters via %s but you don't pass it to the string when executing the query..

So get your database-select in order and pass the row.. otherwise this is a missleading help (even tho it's on the right track) and a -1 should be given for confusion :)

Comment: Python provides a standard DB-API, which is the recommended way to access databases. MySQLdb complies with this API. Also, in your example you don't have the query written anyway, so if you are going into that detail; yours will also break. You also don't loop through the results and there are lots of other small issues.

Comment: `You prepare the string for taking two parameters via %s but you don't pass it to the string when executing the query.` - may I suggest you [read the fine manual](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq#How_do_I_pass_parameters_to_the_cursor.execute_method.3F).

Comment: I always assumed that best practice would be to pass it with the string and not let another function do the job for you (lazyness and increeses the risk of flaws), according to the manual you linked: `"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = '%s'" % "column_value"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import _mysql, sys

argumentfile = sys.argv[1]

with open(argumentfile) as f:
    sqlarguments = f.readlines()

con = None
username, password = 'testuser', 'testpass'
database = 'testdb'

try:
    con = _mysql.connect('localhost', username, password, database)

    for line in sqlarguments:
        con.query("SELECT x, y,z FROM TABLE tablet_vendors WHERE a='%s' and b='%s;'" % line.split('\t'))

        result = con.use_result()
        print "MySQL data returned: %s" % \
            result.fetch_row()[0]
except _mysql.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

More info on Python and MySQL: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/
*(Skip to "First example" if you've got the MySQL and everything setup)*

Note the retrieval of `sqlarguments` which is taken from a textfile which is passed as a parameter to the script as the first and only parameter like: `python2 script.py sqlfile.txt`.
Also note that i assumed that the SQL parameters are delimited by \t (tab) and not spaces, which i then pass in as `a='...'` and `b='...'` encapsulated in `'` in case of spaces.

Comment: Torxed, Thanks I will try tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, good luck and just ask if anything is unclear. Hope the guide is helpful enough and the code should be self explanatory :)

Comment: Torxed, I am not sure where you are getting the arguments from. It seems like your *.py script will have the arguments passed on the command line. However, I need to pass a file name and the actual parameters that go into the where clause of select statement are in that file

Comment: I see, then you'll need to pass the file as an argument.
Now i just took sys.argv which is a list of arguments passed via the command line as you mentioned as  sys.argv = ['script.pu', 'param1', 'param2', ...] :) Will update with a file-reading example.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I caught up on the readline() method which will return the entire line as one string. However, I will need to split the single line "A1 B1" and assign it to two variables. I did not understand the select statement either. I need a select statement that will compare a=A1 and b=B1. Finally, How do I write the output to a file and not just to stdout.

Comment: Note the use of .readlines() on the file-handler, it returns a list of each line, `[line1, line2, line3]` giving you the option to loop through each line one by one, which i do with `for line in sqlarguments:`

Comment: `import mysql` not `_mysql`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: No.. `root@bt:~# python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
>>> import _mysql
>>> import mysql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql
>>>
`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I counter with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620575/python-advantages-and-disvantages-of-mysql-vs-mysqldb

Comment: @Torxed - from the question you linked: `MySQLdb uses DB-API (described in PEP 249) which should be preferred, since it's common to all database drivers. IMHO there is no advantage in going low-level with _mysql.`

Comment: **IMHO** and **low-level == _mysql**, I hardly see the *disadvantage* of going low-level. I try to incurrage the world to NOT become a MAC loving world by using high-level nonensese.. but sure.. a valid point.

Comment: File "mysqlpython.py", line 14, in <module>
    
con.query("SELECT x,y,z from vendors where name='%s' and state='%s' group by a,b" % line.split('\t'))

**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**              Looks like this has got something to do wiht the parameter syntax. I am unable to figure it out. I am reading the documentation and trying to figure it out. Any one who knows exactly what it is?

Comment: You've got more `%s` than you send via `line.split()`.
Check the number of objects returned from `.split()` and count your `%s` in line 14 :)